# c++ Value not being saved to pointer (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

For class we are building a binary search tree.  I believe I should be able to get the bulk of the project myself (isPresent, evaluate, etc), but I'm having issues creating the tree itself.  Given input from main:

```
int main()
{
    BST *bst = new BST();
    bst->add(20, "*");
    bst->add(15, "-");
    bst->add(6, "+");
    bst->add(30, "/");
    bst->add(8, "2");
    bst->add(2, "4");
    bst->add(25, "14");
    bst->add(36, "7");
    bst->add(18, "3");

    cout << ((bst->isPresent(20)) ? "20 - Yes" : "20 - No") << endl;
    cout << ((bst->isPresent(8)) ? "8 - Yes" : "8 - No") << endl;
    cout << ((bst->isPresent(200)) ? "200 - Yes" : "200 - No") << endl;
```

We then go are to use the BST.h that he provided, but that we can add information to (which I have added quite a bit already):

```
class BST
{
public:

    BST();
    void add(int key, string oper);
    bool isPresent(int key) const;

private:


    class Node
    {
    public:
        friend class BST;
        Node()
        {
            mLeft = mRight = nullptr;
            mKey = NULL;
            mOper = "NULL";
            mToken = 0;
        }

        Node(int key, string oper)
        {
            mLeft = mRight = nullptr;
            mKey = key;
            mOper = oper;
            mToken = 0;
        }
        bool find(int x);  // Delete if you don't want it.
        void insert(int key, string oper);

    private:
        Node *mLeft, *mRight;
        int mKey = 0;
        string mOper = "";
        double mToken = 0;
        Node *mRoot;
        Node *helper;
    };
};
```

In the BST.cpp, which can be altered in any way, I have

```
BST::BST()
{
    int key = 0;
    string oper = "NULL";
}


void BST::add(int key, string oper)
{
    Node useThis = Node();
    useThis.insert(key, oper);

}

bool BST::isPresent(int key) const
{
    BST useThis = BST();
    return useThis.find(key);
}

void BST::Node::insert(int key, string oper)
{
    if (mRoot == NULL)
    {
        mRoot = new Node();
        mRoot->mKey = key;
        mRoot->mOper = oper;
        mRoot->mToken;
        mRoot->mLeft = mRoot->mRight = NULL;
        cout << "Finished setting mRoot";
    }


    else
    {
        helper = new Node();
        helper->mKey = key;
        helper->mOper = oper;
        helper->mToken;
        helper->mLeft = mRoot->mRight = NULL;


        if (helper->mToken < mRoot->mToken)
        {
            if (mRoot->mLeft == NULL)
            {
                mRoot->mLeft = helper;
            }
            else
            {
                mRoot->insert(mRoot->mLeft->mKey, mRoot->mLeft->mOper);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (mRoot->mRight == NULL)
            {
                mRoot->mRight = helper;
            }
            else
            {
                mRoot->insert(mRoot->mRight->mKey, mRoot->mRight->mOper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Only relevant code has been inputted**
I'm noticing that each time I go to add, it seems like mRoot has been reset, and the code continues to try to set mRoot to the values that I send it every time (hits the if(mRoot == NULL) multiple times).  Was hoping to find out why the value that I input for mRoot isn't saved when I go to the find method

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that, contrary to your belief, absolutely nothing has been "reset". This is because `BST` contains absolutely nothing that could possibly be reset. So there's nothing to reset. All the shown code does is create various temporary objects, here and there, which get destroyed as soon as the `BST`'s methods return. `add()` for example creates a local instance of `Node`, plays with it, and returns. The local `Node` is now gone. The `BST` is as empty as it's been before. Terms of your homework allow you to add stuff to the `BST`. Well, you haven't added enough.

Comment: Is the constructor for BST() where I need to be putting the *mRoot?  I get what you're saying, but I'm not 100% how to fix it

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes a no sense. A constructor is not where something "needs to be put". A constructor's job is to initialize and construct an instance of a class. That's what it is. That's what it does. And if you're not sure of something, try this: take out a blank piece of paper and write down, using short logical sentences, what you want to do and how you'll do it. [Then schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposal, take what you've written down and translate it into C++.

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
void BST::add(int key, string oper)
{
    Node useThis = Node();
    useThis.insert(key, oper);

}
```

You are every time creating new node and calling insert upon it. And after add function ends, everything you done is lost.

Considering you want to have just one root point, your best option is to create this node just once and remember it (or think again if you really need to have spliedt Node and BST).
Just make it as private parameter for your BST and call insert upon it.